# I want to access the value of the text field with respect to the respective checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

I've 3 text fields and I have 3 checkboxes attached with it. I want to store the values of only those textboxes in one varible whose respective checkboxes is checked. with the help of following codes I can access the values of all the textboxes but for that I've to check all the checkboxes, where as I want to be selective with it. If only 2 checkboxes are checked then I want to have only 2 respective textboxes values stored in a varible.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form action="access.php" method="POST">
        <tr>
        <td>Address:</td><td> <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo "$address"?>" disabled="disabled" id="field1"  /></td>
            <td><input id="CheckBox[]" type="checkbox" onClick="enableText1(this.checked, 'field1');" name="CheckBox1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Source: </td><td><input type="text" name="source" value="<?php echo "$source"?>"  disabled="disabled" id="field2"  /></td>
            <td><input id="CheckBox[]" type="checkbox" onClick="enableText2(this.checked, 'field2');" name="CheckBox2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile:</td><td> <input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo "$mobile"?>" disabled="disabled" id="field3"  /></td>
            <td><input id="CheckBox[]" type="checkbox" onClick="enableText3(this.checked, 'field3');" name="CheckBox3" /></td>></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border:#FFF";>
            <td><input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Update"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['CheckBox1']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['CheckBox2']))
        {
            if(isset($_POST['CheckBox3']))
            {
                $b=array($address,$source,$mobile);
                $a=implode('', $b);
                print $a;
            }
        }
    }   
?>
```

With the help of the above codes if I check all the checkboxes then I am able to print all the 3 textbox's values but if I do not check all the checkboxes then it does not show the value of the respective textboxes. I do not want to change the name of the textboxes name as m going to accept these values to insert into the database. can anyone please sort out this problem? cheers..

Comment: Your question sounds you should read some tutorials first.

Comment: Change the value of attribute "name" of "CheckBox1", "checkboxn", ETC. to "checkbox[]" in the form. Them, in access.php check var_dump($_POST["checkbox"]);, you'll see an array with the checkbox's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access.php

```
 <?php
  $b=array();
  if(isset($_POST['CheckBox1']))
 {
   $b['address'] = $address;
}
     if(isset($_POST['CheckBox2']))
 {
  $b['source'] = $source;
}
    if(isset($_POST['CheckBox3']))
   {
   $b['mobile'] = $mobile;
   }
$a=implode('', $b);
print $a;
 ?>
```

use it.

Comment: Thank you so much... This code is working awesome... But it really proves that I need to improve a lot... Thanks once again to you... You made my work so easy... m so happy...  :)